# What happened to Fang during Hagrid's work with the giants?

Tags: harry-potter

While reading the chapter when Hagrid returns in *Order of the Phoenix* and Fang greets the trio, I wondered where he was staying before Hagrid came back. There's no mention of him during their lessons with Grubblyplank, and I doubt Hagrid took him with them.

He must be somewhere during Hagrid's absence, so where?

Comment: I think he just stayed in the house at Hogwarts, I imagine someone popped in to feed him whilst Hagrid was away.

Answer (score 1):

> “There’s nothin’ that lives in the forest that’ll hurt yeh if yer with
>   me or Fang,” said Hagrid.”
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone*, Chapter 15: *The Forbidden Forest*.</sub>

This shows that Fang is well used to the Forbidden forest and well aware of the whole forest. He can feed himself for sure, not to mention his long teeth.

> “I want Fang,” said Malfoy quickly, looking at Fang’s long teeth.
>
> “All right, but I warn yeh, he’s a coward,” said Hagrid.”
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone*, Chapter 15: *The Forbidden Forest*.</sub>

The below phrase just shows Hagrid's love towards his pets and his innocent mindset that his pets can't find food without his help.That innocence had only let him to raise a Dragon in his own small hut.

> “An’ someone’ll need ter feed Fang while I’m away.”
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*, Chapter 14: *Cornelius Fudge*.</sub>